# Cannot use variable of type in return value

Tags: firebase, go, types

I'm setting up a function which writes json to a firebase storage bucket in golang.
The function `GetStorage` should create a new storage instance and return it from the function to be used in the function `archiveActive`

Im having an issue where I cant figure out what the return type from the `GetStorage` function is.
I get the following error on the line `return client`:

```
cannot use client (variable of type *storage.Client) as *storage.Client value in return statement
```

```
func GetStorage() *storage.Client {
    ctx := context.Background()
    config := &firebase.Config{
        StorageBucket: "myapp-cloud.appspot.com",
    }
    fireBaseApp := push.InitializeAppWithServiceAccount(config)
    client, err := fireBaseApp.Storage(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    return client

}

func GetContext() context.Context {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, zone.Second*50)
    defer cancel()
    return ctx
}

func archiveActive(jsonData string) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, zone.Second*50)
    defer cancel()
    client := GetStorage()
    time := zone.Now().Format("2006-01-02")
    bucket, err := client.DefaultBucket()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    obj := bucket.Object("dev/archives/active/" + time)

    ...
}
```

However, doing it the following way works. As long as the new storage client is made in the same function it is fine. I just need help breaking the function up into smaller pieces.

```
func getStorageConfig() *firebase.Config {
    return &firebase.Config{
        StorageBucket: "myapp-cloud.appspot.com",
    }
}

func getContext() context.Context {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, zone.Second*50)
    defer cancel()
    return ctx
}

func archiveActive(jsonData string) {

    time := zone.Now().Format("2006-01-02")
    ctx := getContext()
    client, err := push.InitializeAppWithServiceAccount(getStorageConfig()).Storage(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    bucket, err := client.DefaultBucket()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    obj := bucket.Object("dev/archives/active/" + time)
    ...
}
```

Comment: The `storage` package declared as the returned type in the first code snippet is not the same `storage` package the `client` variable's type is.

Comment: Are you importing cloud.google.com/go/storage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Client` struct in "firebase.google.com/go/storage" (which is the return value of `fireBaseApp.Storage()`) and in "cloud.google.com/go/storage" (which appears to be the return value of `GetStorage()`).  Both packages have the name `storage` so if you need to import them both you must use an import alias.

I'm not certain without seeing all the code but I think this might work for you:

```
import firebaseStorage "firebase.google.com/go/storage"

...
func GetStorage() *firebaseStorage.Client {
```

Comment: Yes! That worked. Wow that is a confusing situation. Thank you very much.